# MySQL: select a month's data dividing into time slots

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables

Table 1. timeslots

```
CREATE TABLE `timeslots` (
   `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `TodName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   `StartTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
   `EndTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
   `SiteId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
)
```

Table 2. sensorvalues

```
CREATE TABLE `sensorvalues` (
   `SiteID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `MeterID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `Time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
   `SensorValue` double DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`MeterID`,`Time`)
)
```

I have to get the maximum sensor value minus minimum sensor value per-month grouped by timeslots. That is each day hours are divided into three time slots. 1. peak hour (6am - 6pm) 2. normal hours(6pm - 11pm) and 3. off-peak hours(11pm - 6am). I need to get each months respective sensor values for these time slots seperately.

what i am currently doing is seperately find the sensor values for each day and add it like

```
select Max(sv.SensorValue)-min(sv.SensorValue) 
FROM sensorvalues sv 
Where sv.`Time` between '2014-01-01 06:00:00' and  '2014-01-01 17:59:59' and MeterID = 1 ;
```

This takes a lot of time since the sensorvalues table is updated with each minutes data and is huge. Any body could help me or give suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps doing this in one query will help.  If you just want the summary values by month, something like this:

```
SELECT (case when time(time) between '06:00:00' and '17:59:59' then 'peak'
             when time(time) between '18:00:00' and '22:59:59' then 'normal'
             else 'offpeak'
        end) as timegroup,
       Max(sv.SensorValue) - min(sv.SensorValue) 
FROM sensorvalues sv 
WHERE sv.`Time` BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-01-31 23:59:59' AND MeterID = 1
GROUP BY timegroup;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not create the grouping in the query, and then `GROUP BY` it?

```
SELECT MAX(sv.SensorVale) - MIN(sv.SensorValue)
    ,CAST(CASE 
        WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM sv.`Time`) BETWEEN 6 AND 17 THEN 'Peak'
        WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM sv.`Time`) BETWEEN 18 AND 22 THEN 'Normal'
        ELSE 'Off-Peak'
    END AS VARCHAR(8)) AS hourGroup
    ,EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sv.`Time`) AS monthGroup
    ,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sv.`Time`) AS yearGroup
FROM sensorvalues AS sv
WHERE sv.MeterID = 1
GROUP BY hourGroup
    ,monthGroup
    ,yearGroup;
```

This should give you the groupings that you need without a bunch of extra queries. I added in the Month- and Year-based groups because you alluded to those as parameters in your question.

If you wanted to be a touch (and I mean only a little, but it may make a difference based on your record set) more performant, you could convert it into a search `CASE` instead of the value `CASE` I did above:

```
SELECT MAX(sv.SensorVale) - MIN(sv.SensorValue)
    ,CAST(CASE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM sv.`Time`)
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Peak'
        WHEN 7 THEN 'Peak'
        WHEN 8 THEN 'Peak'
        WHEN 9 THEN 'Peak'
        WHEN 10 THEN 'Peak'
        WHEN 11 THEN 'Peak'
        WHEN 12 THEN 'Peak'
        WHEN 13 THEN 'Peak'
        WHEN 14 THEN 'Peak'
        WHEN 15 THEN 'Peak'
        WHEN 16 THEN 'Peak'
        WHEN 17 THEN 'Peak'
        WHEN 18 THEN 'Normal'
        WHEN 19 THEN 'Normal'
        WHEN 20 THEN 'Normal'
        WHEN 21 THEN 'Normal'
        WHEN 22 THEN 'Normal'
        ELSE 'Off-Peak'
    END AS VARCHAR(8)) AS hourGroup
    ,EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sv.`Time`) AS monthGroup
    ,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sv.`Time`) AS yearGroup
FROM sensorvalues AS sv
WHERE sv.MeterID = 1
GROUP BY hourGroup
    ,monthGroup
    ,yearGroup;
```

A bigger query, but the `CASE` itself is more performant. If your record set is small then this will make a minimal impact, but if you are processing records in the tens of millions it will, so I'm just providing it as an alternative.

Comment: Thank you, for the extra suggestions. I got the response almost the same for the two.

Comment: I used 'END AS CHAR(8)'  since there i got an error in casting as 'VARCHAR'